# How to label a road with my symbol multiple times?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, symbology, features

I am trying to label a road that I create with Select Features, with a symbol multiple times along the road. Is it possible to recreate my symbol multiple times along the road to label it?

Comment: What software/version are you using?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Do you have Maplex? Go to data frame properties and look at where it says 'label engine', see if there's an option for maplex.

Comment: Please be aware that there is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to update it with responses to any requested clarifications.  This explains the parts of a question and how comments relate to them: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353

Answer (score 5):

Without the [Maplex label engine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000036000000) your only option using the Standard Label engine is to label each part of the feature:

[image]

Maplex gives more functionality for labeling, to repeat the label go to label density and select the checkbox for Repeat Label:

[image]

Hit the options button and specify how often you want the label to be repeated, either in map units or page units, in this case I want the label to appear every two inches on the final product:

[image]

This may be a bit excessive, change to a repetition interval that is comfortable for you:
[image]